# how to format rows relative to table headers?

Tags: html, powershell

I have a script as follows:

```
$ebody = "
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<table style=`"width:100%`">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Data Source</th>
        <th>dest Server</th>
        <th>Security Option</th>
        <th>Est Size</th>
        <th>Last Updated</th>
    </tr>
</table>
"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++)
{
    $ebody += "
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
    <table style=`"width:100%`">
        <tr>
            <td>$($i)</td>
            <td>$DSource</td>
            <td>$Server</td>
            <td>$Security</td>
            <td>$Size</td>
            <td>$Updated</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    "
if ($i -gt 1)
{Send-MailMessage -To recipient@domain.com -from sender@domain.com -Subject "hi" -body $ebody -BAH -SmtpServer server@domain.com -Port 25 -Credential $cred -usessl}
}
```

i get this as output to email:

[image: table]

i would like to get this kind of output,

[image: desired]

in which the rows adjust relatively to the headers...or if there is a way for the headers to be adjusted to the rows, though i dont think thats possible unless there is some sort of reference way?

so basically ow can i achieve a good relatively padded table with my script requirement being $ebody gets appended to the rows?

EDIT: after applying $ebody changes from Theo's answer. the first iteration row perfectly aligns! but somehow 2nd iteration doesnt...

[image: edit]

Comment: Put the actual data in `<td>` elements instead of table headers (`<th>`)

Comment: @Theo whoops I copied the th twice for stackoverflow. It's already td elements in my code, I just editted the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you get your data from, but for now, in the below example I simply assume the given variables in your code are arrays.
If that is not the case, let me know so we can adjust that inside the loop.

First off, you do not have to add the `<style>` inside the loop. Doing that once at the beginning of the body is enough.
Next, build on the table for as long as you have data and finally close that table.

I used splatting for all the parameters in the Send-MailMessage cmdlet to make better readable code.

```
$ebody = @'
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
              border: 1px solid black;
              border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Data Source</th>
            <th>dest Server</th>
            <th>Security Option</th>
            <th>Est Size</th>
            <th>Last Updated</th>
        </tr>

'@

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
    $ebody += @"
            <tr>
                <td>$i</td>
                <td>$DSource[$i]</td>
                <td>$Server[$i]</td>
                <td>$Security[$i]</td>
                <td>$Size[$i]</td>
                <td>$Updated[$i]</td>
            </tr>

"@
}

$ebody += @"
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"@

if ($i -gt 1) {
    $params = @{
        'To'         = 'recipient@domain.com'
        'From'       = 'sender@domain.com'
        'Subject'    = 'hi'
        'Body'       = $ebody
        'BodyAsHtml' = $true
        'SmtpServer' = 'server.domain.com'
        'Port'       = 25
        'Credential' = $cred
        'UseSsl'     = $true
    }

    Send-MailMessage @params
}
```

Comment: so the if statement and the $ebody += "    </table>" have to be inside the loop in my case. the reason is because i have an if statement wrappers checking for errors in some files and sending emails accordingly. i simplified the post for SO purposes

Comment: i just applied your $ebody changes and the first iteration row returned exactly how i wanted  :) however, the second row does not appear as though its contained in any row. the data is outside the table without borders

Comment: check out my EDIT in the post, i added a picture

Comment: ok so i figured out how to make other iterations become part of the table. but i had ot do it rather in unrecommended way...i removed enclosing table tag </table> because whats happening is once the iteration hits again in my script it gets excluded since the table was closed in 1st iteration. but i know this is not good practice. if there is a better way that i can accomplish this of course it'd be better

Comment: @Cataster Didn't see your latest comment in time.. I added html, head and body tags to the html output. On my machine this works, but I guess it also has to do with the email client you are using. Outlok can be difficult to render html correctly. Glad I could help.

Comment: yes this is excellent :) but its not an outlook issue (i know it has issues) but its rather my code is slightly different than yours for a reason. you are putting this part $ebody += @"
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"@ outside the loop. in my case it has to be inside the loop for complex reasons. one way that helped was removing the enclosing table tag, but i know this is not recommended.